# What is the encoding of Open XML file

Tags: c#, java, encoding

I open it with an editor and shows as UTF8-BOM, but when i get the content using C# and send it to Java web service and receive as UTF-8 encoding, the content changed.

Where wrong?

Comment: How did you get the content in C#?

Comment: In what way did the content change? How are you receiving it on the Java side?

Comment: @Mark just HttpUtility.UrlEncode(content) and send to java server

Comment: @Jone Skeet some French character changed.

Answer (score 0):

When you store something in a .NET string, it is encoded as UTF-16.

Comment: Should I convert utf16 to utf8 and send to java and get the result and converted it back?

Comment: Which encoding is the Java web service using to send the result?

Comment: In that case, you may need to convert it back.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways one can corrupt the encoding.

Get the in-flight message, and review it. Figure out if the encoding is still OK (problem is on Java side), or wrong already (problem is on C# side). Continue to narrow the search field until you see the root cause.